# Overriding ostream behavior for basic data types via it's streambuf

Tags: c++, streambuf

I would like to perform some specialized processing of the data written to a std::ostream as it is being written.  Lets say (for simplicity's sake), every time any of the basic data types are injected to my ostream, I want a comma to follow the injection.

```
template<class T>
class MyOstream : public T
{
    // Impossible code
};

#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i = -2;
    double d = 3.21;
    char[] s = "char array";
    bool b = false;
    MyOstream<ostringstream> mos;
    mos << i << d << s << b;
    cout << mos.str() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

and I want the output to be:

```
-2,3.21,char array,0,
```

As I recall, the only virtual method defined for std::ostream is the destructor, so the normal approach of method overrides is out of the question.  But would it be possible to achieve this behavior by using a specialized streambuf?  streambufs DO have several virtual methods.  I know there are virtual methods used to update pointers as data is written, but I don't yet fully understand all of these methods.  I was hoping someone could tell me if perhaps one of these methods is called exactly once with each such injection and thus give me a way to do my magic.  But if, for example, a large character array (that exceeds the buffer size) results in several calls to that same method (to move data through the streambuf in chunks), then I'm sunk.

The only other alternative I have is to wrap the ostream instead of inheriting from it.  This is easy enough, but such an approach precludes the possibility of passing the ostream to a third-party print routine (that expects a std::ostream).

Yes, I know what I'm contemplating is pure evil.

Comment: You don't need to inherit from a stream for this to work. Instead all you need is a lot of overloaded versions of `operator<<` in your class, and they simply append to a string which is then returned by the `str` (or similar) function.

Comment: It's not necessarily my class.  I want this behavior for ANY class (possibly third-party) that streams to MyOstream.

Comment: I still don't think you should inherit the actual stream class. You mention `streambuf`. That's usually the class to inherit from. That way you don't have to overload any of the output functions. Regarding other user-defined classes, that's solved the usual way: With *them* overloading a global `operator<<` function to "output" a representation of itself, and then your buffer (or stream) class can just insert the comma-separator as it would for standard types.

Comment: Also, you can get a lot of help by utilizing the [Boost iostreams library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/iostreams/doc/index.html).

Comment: The reason I'm inheriting from ostream is irrelavant to my question.  I probably shouldn't have brought it up, but I don't think you're answering my question:  are you sure it's even possible to achieve the behavior I'm looking for (specialized processing for the insertion of a standard data type) by subclassing streambuf?

Comment: is it "_even possible to achieve the behavior I'm looking for (specialized processing for the insertion of a standard data type) by subclassing streambuf_": It is **not**